# Language settings

Tags: system, language

I'm trying to configure the language of elementary 0.4 in settings panel, but a message with yellow background keeps asking to "complete the installation".

So I click on this button "complete the installation", but if I logout, this message is still there...

Picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/adOS4.jpg

How can I fix that ?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue, to fix it unlock, select and remove each other language listed except yours with the minus symbol below the list.

Comment: Thank you

I removed all unsued lunguage and I could complete the installation of my language

Answer (score 1):

To "complete installation" you have to unlock the panel with the lock button ("Unlock" or "Déverrouiller" in the french version), as this changement requires administrator rights.

Comment: I did that, but it's keep asking to "complete installation"...

Comment: Did you complete the installation? It should disappear after this…

Comment: I click always on 'unlock' (and I enter the password) then "complete installation". After that, the yellow bar of "complete installation" disappear. Then I wait 10 mins and I logout or reboot the computer. After that, I go back to the language settings, and the yellow bar with  "complete installation" shows up again...

Comment: You might have to remove some (or all) of the unused languages as Lupo pointed out because their support is not "complete".